# Creating a Template Like System in cPanel

Tags: cpanel, template

I am creating a medium sized website using cPanel and their File Manager system and the majority of my pages are going to be the same with a different title and content section and I wanted to see if there is a system for making one general template file and then having all the other pages inherit from that file so all I have to do is have a content and title section and the rest of the links, headers, and whatnot can be changed throughout the site by just changing one file.

Is there anything like this?  I have used Jinaj2 in python and a few other systems for other server scripting languages but I am not sure how to implement it with cPanel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

cPanel isn't a hosting environment or server-side scripting language. It's a control panel for general website management (email, ftp, etc). It can't do things like templates or include files. You'll need to use Server Side Includes, PHP includes, etc. like you've used in the past to accomplish this. If you're going to use cPanel for file management then you'll just need to code it correctly and upload the file with the right extension for this work (just like you would if you used FTP, SFTP, etc).

Comment: Okay thanks.  I hadn't used a system like this before but that is the answer I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Most hosting companies which have cPanel installed have a file manager setup, you could technically browse to your www, public_html folder and create a new index files and write the HTML by hand and save it.